# How does gradle shadow plugin deal with OSGi structures?

Tags: osgi, datanucleus, uberjar, gradle-shadow-plugin

I'm using the shadow plugin in gradle build process to package an uber jar for my executable. However, this involves `datanucleus` which is OSGi structured. When I use `shadowJar` task in gradle, the `plugin.xml` is lost. Does the gradle shadow plugin has a way to deal with this type of dependencies? I have been searching around but haven't found anything useful other than manually merging things or moving away from shadow plugin.

Comment: FYI "plugin.xml" is nothing to do with OSGi. It is a mechanism for providing a plugin system for applications, and was originally developed for Eclipse. DataNucleus use it since they support a flexible system allowing users to plug-in extra handling, but they have no dependency on Eclipse. OSGi only requires MANIFEST.MF IIRC (which isn't your problem here).

Comment: Additional problem will be if you have multiple plugin.xml files in the Jars you are combining, because if they are relevant for you application they would need to get merged.